# Is there anywhere in Sitecore where I can add author notes about a version of a content item?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.5

The customer is asking if there is any place in Sitecore where a content author could add internal notes for an individual version of a content item.  The note might say something like "I changed the content field to include updated descriptions" or something.  This is different from simply adding a comment when you submit an item in to workflow.  They want the ability to look at different versions of content items and see what the different changes were easily with comments and specifically why content was changed.

Does anything like this exist in Sitecore out of the box?

Corey

Comment: How this field should differs from standard versioned field? You should add versioned field and extend interface.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it in the box. But you could easily add an extra field to accomplish this. Best to use a base template with this field in it and inherit all your other templates from this one. You can name your own section and field, even include descriptions for the editors or add rules to validate the input.

You would need some extra coding to clear the field when a new version is created. Otherwise you will copy the text from the originating version. The item:versionAdded event is an option.